# Partial sum of Fourier series

Tags: analysis, fourier-series

I found the coefficients of the Fourier series. The partial sum of the Fourier series is defined on the interval $[0,2\pi]$ by

$$S_N(x) = \frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^{N}[ a_n \cos(nx) + b_n \sin(nx)],$$

where

$$a_0 =\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} f(x)\, dx, $$
$$a_n = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} f(x) \cos(nx)\, dx,$$
$$b_n =\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} f(x) \sin(nx)\, dx.$$

Is there any way to put all the coefficients in the partial sum and to derive the function? I struggled after I put everything in one equation to see if it can be simplified more.

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I am new to this website, I try to fix the way to write equations. I am so sorry

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Thank you ! @Gary

Comment: At the moment it is not clear what you are asking for. What would you like to achive/do exactly?

Comment: if I plug a0,an,and bn into S_N(x). How could be simplified more ? Can we solve the sum or S_n(x) be written in simple way ?

Comment: https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Dirichlet_kernel

Answer (score 0):

I found the above question might be a classic issue. Its digital form is called **compressed-sensing**.
Here's [a link](https://www.math.hkbu.edu.hk/%7Ettang/UsefulCollections/compressed-sensing1.pdf) and page 6 introduces this problem.